# How to make wordpress backend mobile optimized.?

Tags: plugins, themes, users, profiles, optimization

I have a membership website where my users can create their own page. Most of my users are from mobiles (they do not have laptops).

When I open my website in android chrome browser, the WordPress back end is not that much optimize. It most times freeze or slow or hangs.

Like there are plugins to make WordPress front end mobile optimized; is their any such plugin or codes to make WordPress back end mobile optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Your core mistake is to let users get to the admin. A proper solution is to create "admin" type of screens for your users in which there will be a more focused UX for what they can and likely to do. As part of creating it you can also optimize the experience to low power android phones.

Comment: I use "user access" plugin & only give access to create,edit,delete their own page only. They no access to anything else.

Comment: than I am not sure what solution you look for. editing content is JS heavy which might be problematic on low power pones. The only option is to not use any fancy editor for those users

Comment: @Markalpun, so my only option is to instruct users to go to internet parlors to create their own page. Anyway thanks for helping.

Comment: I am not realy sure what is it that you expect? if someone is using a low powered phone he will have a problem with many sites. What you need to do is put an effort and design editing experience that will fit those kinds of phones if this is very important for you. One of the options is to disable the editor and edit content as pure text (if that is where the bottle neck is)